# PopupDialog wont work when trying to show it from different function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have `PopupDialog` component that Im trying to implement in my app and Im struggling to make it work when calling it from inside of a function.
What I mean by that is, i have a button that has `onPress` prop that invoking a function, I want to add to this function `this.popupDialog.show();` so it also show the `PopupDialog` on same press. But when trying to do so it's not working and all it does it's print the `Text` that is inside the `PopupDialog` at the top right cornet of my screen. But When Im trying to invoke it like this: `onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show()}` (without `this.functionX`) everything is works as expected.

CODE:

```
  this.state.sumAll.map((detail) => (

    <View key={detail[0]}>            

    <PopupDialog
      ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
    >
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    </PopupDialog>


      <MapView.Marker
      key={Math.random()}
      coordinate= {
          {
              latitude: this.latIfUndefined(detail[0]),
              longitude: this.lonIfUndefined(detail[1])
          }
      }
      title={this.props.address}
      description={``}
      onPress={() => this.functionX()}
      image={require('../../assets/img/1.png')}
      /> 
    </View>
  ))
```

NOTE: above is the code where `this.popupDialog.show();` is inside `this.functionX()` and it's not working it's just print `hello` at the top corner of the screen on when the view is rendered.

but when the code is:

```
  this.state.sumAll.map((detail) => (

    <View key={detail[0]}>            

    <PopupDialog
      ref={(popupDialog) => { this.popupDialog = popupDialog; }}
    >
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    </PopupDialog>


      <MapView.Marker
      key={Math.random()}
      coordinate= {
          {
              latitude: this.latIfUndefined(detail[0]),
              longitude: this.lonIfUndefined(detail[1])
          }
      }
      title={this.props.address}
      description={``}
      onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show();}
      image={require('../../assets/img/1.png')}
      /> 
    </View>
  ))
```

Everything works fine. The problem is that I need `this.functionX` to invoke both functions on press. couldn't manage it.

Comment: `function` is a reserved keyword and you cannot use it to name something. choose something different, maybe that is the reason why it is failing after all.

Comment: I would also say that your way of doing things is not correct. You should avoid using Refs when you can. So you could do something like {this.state.showPopup && <PopupDialog>...</PopupDialog> and to display it you'd just do this.setState({showPopup: true});

Comment: can you show how you implemented `functionX` in your class? Also please write correct javascript code (declare the class correctly)

Comment: @Scalpweb  I took it right out of the documentation of this component
@Luke `functionX` implement like this: `functionX = () => {}`

Comment: btw you are aware of that you overwrite `this.popupDialog` for every element in `sumAll`?

Comment: @Luke yes, every popup has dif values

Comment: no, what I am saying is, that `this.popupDialog` is always just one popup, and it is the latest one. Your ref function gets called on every map, so this.popupDialog gets overwritten all the time

Comment: what does functionX do exactly? do you maybe set some state? that would cause an (asynchronous) rerender. That might cause the unexpected behavior.